# Are there any good resources that describe how https/SSL/TLS works?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I find it really hard to find online resources which go through the details of the following aspects of SSL work.

Is a certificate of a website signed with the public key of a Certificate Authority, or does the browser actually contact the Certificate Authority to verify the certificate...

Any good and clear technical sources for info are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html decribes it en detail.

Comment: in two words: yeah! finally! To bad it doesn't have references, but other than that, it confirms what I thought, so I trust it. Great article.

Comment: ps: Im going to turn of my wireshark now, because the work has been done.

Comment: for further information you can read the corresponding RFCs 5246, etc. But in my opinion most RFCs are dry to read.

Comment: I have to take my words back btw, the article does have references, but not as foothnotes, just as links in the text. I did look at that rfc, but it is particularly dry and I did not manage to extract the information I was looking for in an efficient manner.